# C pointers - Different address

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

I'm trying to learn about C pointers but I cannot understand somethings...
The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int *x, int *y);

void foo(int *x, int *y) {
    printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", &x, &y);
    *x = 5;
    *y = 6;
}

int main(void) {
    int a, b;
    printf("a = %p\nb = %p\n", &a, &b);
    foo(&a, &b);
    return 0;
}
```

Why are the addresses different? The first `printf` (main) output two addresses. the other `printf` (foo) output different addresses. I'm passing addresses to foo (& operator).

Answer (score 8):

In `main`, you're printing addresses of `x` and `y`, but in `foo`, you're printing addresses of *pointers* to `x` and `y`.  You *meant* to write:

```
printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", x, y);
```

(notice the lack of `&` before `x` and `y`)

Answer (score 3):

because `printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", &x, &y);` print the address of x and y, instead of their value. You need to replace it with

`printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", x, y);`

to yield same results.

Answer (score 3):

Your foo function takes pointers to int as parameters, that means that x and y are already pointers in foo and their values are the addresses you want to print.

Instead you print the addresses of these pointers.
Your print should look more like

```
printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", x, y);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `printf` call in `foo` is being passed the addresses of the pointers, i.e., variables of type `int **`.  If you remove the `&` symbols from the `printf` call you should get the same addresses as from the `printf` call in `main`.

Answer (score 2):

First, about your C:

If you are defining the entire function above main(), you need not include  its prototype before it.
So delete the 2nd line:

> ```
> void foo(int *x, int *y);
> ```

Now, for the real matter at hand, a pseudo memory map would come handy:

```
    a      b
 --------------
|  5   |   6   | <- data
 --------------
 [1000]  [1004]  <- address

    x        y
 ----------------
|  1000  | 1004  | <- data
 ----------------
  [2000]   [2004]  <- address
```

So here, you shall get:

```
a = 1000 b = 1004  (the addresses of a & b)
x = 2000 y = 2004  (the addresses of x & y)
```

If you want:

```
x = 1000 y = 1004
```

Type,

```
printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", x, y);
```

as is clear from the memory map above.

Answer (score 1):

In main, you are printing the adresses of the local variables `a` and `b`. In `foo` you are printing the addresses of the local variables `x` and `y`, not the addresses retained in them. You need to drop the `&` in `foo` if you want them to match.

Remember that a pointer is a variable that holds a memory address. You're confusing the address of the pointer variable with the address retained in the pointer. You need to print what the pointers hold if you want the two prints to match.

Answer (score 1):

In main, you are printing addresses of a & b variables..but in function foo(), you are printing addresses of pointers to x & y

Answer (score 0):

The first `printf` in main() displays the addresses of main's `a` and `b`.

The foo's `printf` displays the addresses of `x` and `y`.

What you want, I guess, is to display the addresses from main() of `a` and `b`

Change foo:

```
  printf("x = %p\ny = %p\n", x, y);
```

to display the addresses as they come from main()

Answer (score 0):

In main, the address of variables a and b is printed. In function foo(), the dress of pointers x and y is printed, those are pointing to variables and b.