# Pointers in C: why is the * needed in *address_of_x = &x when getting the address of x?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

Suppose we have the following code, which takes `x`, stores the value `4` in it, then stores the address of `x` in a pointer variable:

```
int x = 4;
int *address_of_x = &x;
```

What is the purpose of the `*` in `int *address_of_x`?
I understand `*` to be used for dereferencing a pointer - it takes an address and tells you what's stored there. But if an address is being stored, then what are we dereferencing? Or are we not dereferencing anything at all? Why isn't it written as:

```
int address_of_x = &x;
```

Comment: It's not dereferencing but a type. Context matters.

Comment: `*` can mean a whole lot of different things in the C language, depending on context. Your C programming book should make this clear.

Comment: I have a sense of duplication.

Comment: Definitely duplication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C pointers - Different address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815095/c-pointers-different-address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` in `int *address_of_x = &x;` is not de-referencing [@Eugene Sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437772/pointers-in-c-why-is-the-needed-in-address-of-x-x-when-getting-the-addres#comment81829959_47437772).
It is part of the type declaration: [pointer to int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*address_of_x%3B).

```
int x = 4;
int *address_of_x = &x;
```

same as

```
int x = 4;          // declare x as int
int *address_of_x;  // declare address_of_x as pointer to int
address_of_x = &x;  // Assign the address of x to address_of_x
```

---

> Why isn't it written as: `int address_of_x = &x;`

`&x` is not an `int`.  `&x` is an `int *`, a pointer (or address).  A pointer is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

That's the definition of a pointer, the type for `address_of_x` variable is `int *`, a pointer to `int`. There's no "dereference" happening there.

> Why isn't it written as:
>
> ```
>    int address_of_x = &x;
> ```

Well, two things

- C is a strongly typed language.
- the variable names do not carry any connection with their type

Comment: @DavidBowling that's obviously there, comes with the understanding of types themselves.

Answer (score 2):

In an *expression*, the `*` is the dereference operator. In a *declaration* (which you have here), it's part of the syntax of a *pointer declarator*. You're declaring `address_of_x` to be a *pointer to `int`* rather than just an `int`.

The idea that was behind this syntax is that declarations and usage of identifiers should look similar (you typically **use** a pointer by dereferencing it) for convenience.

Also note that the `*` is needed for every identifier declared as a pointer, even if you declare multiple identifiers in a single declaration, like this:

```
int *a, *b;
```

If you write

```
int *a, b;
```

instead, `b` would **not** be a pointer. In general, it's best practice to avoid declaring more than one identifier per declaration, though.

Answer (score 2):

`int *address_of_x = &x;` isn't an assignment. `int *address_of_x = &x;` is a **declaration** (`int *address_of_x`) with **initialization** (`= &x`) (note that in pre-historic C, initializations (as opposed to assignments) were done without the `=`, which made them even more distinct from assignments).

Declarations in C mirror usage. `int *address_of_x` declares that `*address_of_x` is of type `int`, ergo `address_of_x` is of type *pointer to int*. The `= &x` part then initializes this *pointer to int* to `&x` (address of `x`).

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: **The asterisk in a variable declaration or definition statement is NOT a dereference operator.** Instead it's a modifier.

In the given context, an asterisk means "Define the mext identifier as a pointer to the base type".

You surely won't ask why `[10]` doesn't mean "take the 10th element of the array" in `int a[10]`. Well, so-so. The brackets here also aren't the bracket operator, for exactly the same reason.

> Why isn't it written as:
>
> ```
>    int address_of_x = &x;
> ```

The compiler *never* tries to interpret the literal meaning of identifiers. It only looks for modifiers when determining the type of an iddentifier in a declaration statement.

i.e., this code will not work as what it looks like:

```
int *not_a_pointer, not_an_array[10];
float a_character;
```

Answer (score 0):

`int *address_of_x = &x;` *declares* a variable of type "pointer to int" (`int *address_of_x`) and then *initializes* it with the address of x (`= &x`).

So this `*` is not the dereferencing but is part of the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

These two snippets are functionally the same:

```
int *address_of_x = &x;
```

and

```
int *address_of_x;
address_of_x = &x;
```

In the first case you defined and initialised the pointer all in one statement, but it can *look* like the wrong syntax. In the second example the definition and the value assignment are separate statements, and the code is clearer.

There is no dereferencing (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Read it as -
`int x = 4; int* address_of_x = &x;`

1. You Created a variable x of type int and stored a value 4 in it.
2. You created a variable address_of_x of type int* i.e. pointer to an int value, and stored address of x in it.

Note : Pointer is not just an address, its an address which points to some variable of type pointerType.

```
pointerType* pointer = &variable
```

You can go through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M , the best tutorial on pointers in universe :)

Comment: This question was answered and accepted 6 years ago